# Ubuntu: Port is open but no listening processes, still responses "404 Not Found"

Tags: docker, port, netstat, zombie-process

I'm developing various applications in docker containers locally. After some time I came up with some strange issue.

### The Issue

As always, I started a container with the port 8080 being exposed to the host. Then I did some of my work but as I wanted to view the application in browser (localhost:8080) it returned a simple page with just: "404 page not found".

I wondered why that was happening cause from the container I could access the webapp without any problems.

So I restarted that container, still the same. I shut the container down and... still the same!
Even though my container - which accepted the port binding onto 8080 without errors - is shut down, it still prints this text in browser.

Whatever I do, this "404 page not found" message is now always there.

### Digging into it

To get a grasp on what's goin on or fix this I tried the following:

1. look for applications listening on 8080 (`sudo lsof -i :8080` or `sudo netstat -nlp | grep 8080`): gives empty result
2. prune docker (`docker system prune -a`)
3. restart docker service (`sudo service docker restart`)
4. restart Kubuntu (`sudo restart`)
5. reset network (disabling and enabling per GUI)

None of those steps resolved this problem for me, neither I can't find any related information while googling.
I have absolutely no clue what is happening here!

#### System / Software info

```sh
# OS Version
$ lsb_release -a 
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 19.04
Release:        19.04
Codename:       disco

# docker
$ docker --version
Docker version 19.03.2, build 6a30dfca03

# find process using :8080
$ sudo lsof -i :8080
$ sudo netstat -nlp | grep 8080
# in both cases there is no output

# wget
$ wget localhost:8080
--2019-10-18 00:20:52--  http://localhost:8080/
Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:8080... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2019-10-18 00:20:52 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

How can I find that process which is listening on 8080? (it also confuses me that I can still run docker containers without error on that port)

I'm damn thankful for every hint you can give me.

Comment: seems like some other process runing, just try to publish some other port and then verigy like `docker run -it -p 8090:8080 your_image"

Comment: @Adiii i didnt clarify my question actualy, it's not about how i can use docker on different port rather than how i can find that process which is listening on 8080 when all tools I know off don't show anything

Answer (score 4):

For anyone who may run into this recently, I ran into a nearly identical behavior after installing Rancher/K3s in place of Kubuntu. Traefik was being deployed by default as part of the base install, and was gobbling up any requests which would normally have been handled by my host instance of NGINX. This is stated in the documentation but was not indicated at surface-level when I installed K8s. [Reference](https://rancher.com/docs/k3s/latest/en/networking/#traefik-ingress-controller)